# $dirty check on multiple forms (modals)

Tags: angularjs

I have a list with links created via ng-repeat. Clicking one gives you a modal to edit the item when ready the modal get's closed.
The form has a:
`ng-disabled="editClientForm.$invalid && !editClientForm.$dirty"`

to check if it's valid and updated before you can submit.

The problem now is that when opening one of the items and editing to make it $dirty all other items get dirty when opening them. Is there a way around this problem without giving all forms a unique name?

Comment: You can manually set the field to pristine state (but it depends on your implementation).

Comment: Can you create a fiddle demonstrating your issue?

Comment: Yes, furthering what @ExpertSystem said, perhaps you can set the field to pristine when the modal opens. Can you provide some more code samples to better illustrate your implementation?

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I thought it was Angular specific but now I found out it's something with the Ionic Framework which keeps data in memory.